# iOS 11 - Suggestions for Custom View Controller Not Loading - Crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

My app has recently (iOS 11) started crashing when a custom UIViewController is loaded:

The crash occurs at the line:

`PDFViewController *pdfvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PDFView"];`

I confirm:

- In the storyboard I am referencing the correct custom class `PDFViewController` and the ID is correct `PDFView`.
- The super class has initWithCoder

The exact error I get is:

```
[PDFViewController initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c0012320
2017-09-26 22:35:44.578082+0900 flightcomp[9764:3233421] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PDFViewController initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c0012320'
```

Now I've really searched around crazy on this - been through so many StackOverflow and Google pages to find nothing.

So my question is - could someone, please suggest a handful of things that could likely be causing this issue so I can further debug.

Thanks.

p.s.

The .h for PDFViewController looks like:

```
@interface PDFViewController : UIViewController <UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate>
```

The .m for PDFViewController looks like:

```
@implementation PDFViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: You have viewcontroller in XIB ?  I can see `initWithNibName`

Comment: Yes I do have the viewController in the storyboard. Is there something wrong there?

Comment: is your `initWithNibName` Method call from some where ?

Comment: As mentioned above - `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PDFView"]`

Comment: Sometimes it happes when the project is moved from one version to a new one. Try to clean files and the simulator. For example, a quick test could be starting the app in a different simulator, one you never used before with that app and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Let me clear one thing there is no relation between `initWithNibName` and `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` , I don't understand  why you think so , Put break point in this method may be it is unnecessary or remove this method and try

Comment: Sorry - so you mean remove `PDFViewController *pdfvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PDFView"];` ? If so what will I push onto the navigation controller - i.e. when: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:pdfvc animated:YES];`

Comment: I mean remove `initWithNibName`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSneC.png

The issue is that Apple as of iOS 11 has now included PDFKit as a framework. I believe that PDFViewController is now a reserved name for this framework. I had the same issue and after changing PDFViewController to SuperDuperPDFViewController worked just fine.

Comment: Ahhhh!! That explain's everything.
So i actually created another view and another controller (naturally using PDFViewControllerTwo) and assumed because it was new it worked.
When i deleted PDFViewControllerTwo to check the original (as it was just a duplicate) it began crashing again.
Thanks so much for the confirmation - wish the error message said that :)

Comment: Thank you, it's working. but why it's didn't show any error while compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Rename PDFView to something like MyPDFView.